# ReactJs: How to get proper variable from Router path link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

`<Link to="/category/{card.title}">View List</Link>`

Above I'm switching routes from my homepage to the category page and trying to pass the value of **card.title** into the **Category component**.

The URL title:
[image]

---

Then inside my **Category component**:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        title: props.title
    };

    console.log('props', props);
    console.log('props.location', props.location);
}

componentDidMount() {
    // console.log('Category componentDidMount this.state', this.state);
    console.log('%c Category componentDidMount this.state', 'background: #222; color: #bada55', this.state);
}
```

props:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't be `<Link to={"/category/" + card.title}>View List</Link>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`card.title` is a value, so you need to pass it like this:

```
<Link to={`/category/${card.title}`}>View List</Link>
```

or use `+` like this:

```
<Link to={"/category/" + card.title}>View List</Link>
```

If you use `""` then whole part will become a string, dynamic value will not get replaced.

Check the [mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more details on **template literals.**

**Suggestion:**

I will suggest you to define a param with route category, that param will have the value of `card.title` then inside category component you can access that by `this.props.params.ParamName`.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah the template literals was what I needed :) curious tho... I'm trying to pass in the card.title into the props. However there is no params key. I also tried with `?category=${card.title}` however it just shows up in `props.location.search`

Comment: do one thing you can pass that as a `query parameter` also, like this: `to={'category/?title=' + card.title}` now in category component you can access the value by `this.props.location.query.title` it will print the proper value, i am assuming category is route of Category component :)

Answer (score 1):

```
render () {
   const {title} = this.state;
   const myLink = `/category/${title}`;
   return ( 
       <Link to={myLink} />
   );

}
```